# Auto Hiding CDockablePane on creation

Tags: c++, mfc

I have 3 dockable panes, each containing 1 image. One is on the left, one on the right and one not visible. The problem is, I would like to have the one on the right hidden by default to let the one on the left take the entire space. I have searched through the doc to find I should call the following on my pane, but nothing happens.

```
ToggleAutoHide();
```

I don't know what I am missing... here is my creation code in case it helps:

```
// image docking panel creation
if (!m_wndRawImage.Create(_T("Raw Image"), this, imgRect, TRUE, ID_VIEW_RAWIMGWND, dwPaneStyle| CBRS_RIGHT, AFX_CBRS_REGULAR_TABS, AFX_CBRS_RESIZE))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create image tab window\n");
    return -1;
}

if (!m_wndRefImage.Create(_T("Reference Image"), this, imgRect, TRUE, ID_VIEW_REFIMGWND, dwPaneStyle| CBRS_RIGHT))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create image tab window\n");
    return -1;
}

if (!m_wndCalibImage.Create(_T("Calibrated Image"), this, imgRect, TRUE, ID_VIEW_CALIBIMGWND, dwPaneStyle| CBRS_RIGHT))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create image tab window\n");
    return -1;
}

m_wndImagePane1.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT | CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT);
m_wndImagePane2.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT | CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT);
m_wndImagePane3.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT | CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT);

CDockingManager::SetDockingMode(DT_SMART);

EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
EnableAutoHidePanes(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);


// image panes
DockPane(&m_wndImagePane3);
CDockablePane* pTabbedBar2 = NULL;
m_wndImagePane2.AttachToTabWnd(&m_wndImagePane3, DM_SHOW, FALSE, &pTabbedBar2);
m_wndImagePane2.ShowPane(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
m_wndImagePane3.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);
m_wndImagePane3.ToggleAutoHide(); //<---- Problem is here

DockPane(&m_wndImagePane1);
m_wndImagePane1.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can no one help me? T.T
I could always leave it with everything visible since the user can decide how it'll appear the next time the program starts (since the dockPanes positioning is remembered), but I would've like to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I was understand your problem correctly, you want to hide a pane in app startup.

I use `ON_WM_SHOWWINDOW()` Message to hide pane. like this:

Add this to `CMainFrame` Class declaration:

```
afx_msg void OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus);
```

And add this to Message map:

```
ON_WM_SHOWWINDOW()
```

And add this to your main code:

```
void CMainFrame::OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus)
{
    CFrameWndEx::OnShowWindow(bShow, nStatus);

    // Hide Properties pane in startup
    m_wndProperties.SetAutoHideMode(FALSE, CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    m_wndProperties.ShowPane(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
}
```

Hope it can help!

Comment: mainframe->onshowwindow is not being called on startup. only on shutdown. the only way I found that works is to settimer(ID,200,0) to keep trying pane.toggleautohide, until it is hidden. then kill the timer. pane.toggleautohide only works after a certain time has passed since mainframe oncreate. using toggle/set-autohidemode in oncreate does nothing. it is very annoying that we have to get the hide animation in the beginning.

Comment: hmm, it is only if it was pinned last time the application was open. I think the last layout is being read from registry after oncreate, thus overwriting any changes Im making in oncreate...

Comment: @MichaelNielsen In that case you should hide pane after loading layout properties by MFC. But I'm sorry that I can't help further because I have no MFC or visual studio on my PC ATM

Answer (score 0):

For the posterity.

1. Add new public method to your `CMainFrame` class:

```cpp
void CMainFrame::HidePanes()
{
    m_wndProperties.ShowPane(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
}
```

2. Call this method from the end of your `CMyApp::InitInstance` method:

```cpp
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;
    ...
    
    pMainFrame->HidePanes();
    pMainFrame->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
    pMainFrame->UpdateWindow();
}
```